# In R, how do I filter a dataframe based on differences between dates in rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, date

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

# generate data frame
id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1) # User ID
date <- c("2021-12-26", "2021-12-19", "2021-12-15", "2021-12-07", "2021-11-11", "2021-11-05", "2021-09-17","2021-09-17", "2021-10-08", "2021-10-06", "2021-10-01", "2021-09-30", "2022-01-30", "2022-01-24", "2022-01-18", "2022-01-13") # Date the form was submitted
variable1 <- c(10, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, 7, 6, 9, NA, NA, NA, 6, 8, NA, NA)
variable2 <- c(5,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,4,3,2,5,6,5,4)
sample_data <- data.frame(id, date, variable1, variable2)
sample_data <- sample_data %>%
  mutate(date=as.Date(date, format="%Y-%m-%d"))

#   id       date variable1 variable2
#1   1 2021-12-26        10         5
#2   1 2021-12-19        NA         2
#3   1 2021-12-15        NA         3
#4   1 2021-12-07        NA         4
#5   2 2021-11-11         8         6
#6   2 2021-11-05        NA         7
#7   3 2021-09-17         7         8
#8   4 2021-09-17         6         9
#9   5 2021-10-08         9         1
#10  5 2021-10-06        NA         4
#11  5 2021-10-01        NA         3
#12  5 2021-09-30        NA         2
#13  1 2022-01-30         6         5
#14  1 2022-01-24         8         6
#15  1 2022-01-18        NA         5
#16  1 2022-01-13        NA         4

# get the date from entries with variable1
sample_data <- sample_data %>%
  mutate(date2=as.Date(ifelse(!is.na(variable1),paste(date,sep=""), NA)))
```

in which each row is a separate entry (e.g. a form submission), **id** corresponds to the user id (which is unique to the user, but each user may have more than one entry), **date** is the date of the entry, and **variable1** and **variable2** are two different variables — while **variable2** is required (i.e. no missing values), **variable1** isn't.

I want to compare **variable1** with **variable2** over the 4 weeks prior to **variable1** for each user, *as long as there is at least one entry for each week during those 4 weeks*. I'm kind of puzzled on how to do that.

Basically, I think I should filter the data frame for users with at least one valid **variable1** entry, get the date from this entry (**date2** column), and then get all the entries for the 28 days (7 days × 4 weeks) prior to this date. Finally, because I'm only interested in data from users who have *at least* one entry **each week** during those 28 days, I need to filter those users who have at least one entry for the *date2 to date2 - 7 days* range, one entry for the *date2 - 7 to date2 - 14* range, one entry for the *date2 - 14 to date2 - 21* range, and one entry for the *date2 - 21 to date2 - 28* range).

The problem is, I've been using R for a few months "only", and I have no idea how to approach this problem code-wise.

Does anyone know of the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 3 clarifying questions - 1) what do you mean more precisely when you say "over the 4 weeks prior to variable1 for each user,". 2) "there is at least one entry for each week during those 4 weeks" - do you mean at least one entry for **variable1**? and 3) I don't understand what is the use of `sample_data` to solve this problem.

Comment: @ValeriVoev: Thank you. This is mock data, the actual dataset contains private user data that I could not post publicly. This from an online form that users may fill in at anytime. Some users fill the form daily while other only once a week, etc. V1 asks the user how they've been "feeling" for the past 4 weeks. V2 asks the user how they feel "today". I want to study the correlation, responsiveness, etc., between V1 and V2. Because V1 looks at a 4 weeks period, I need to filter the users who have at least some V2 data (i.e., at least 1 entry) from each week that V1 concerns. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to crack this :). The solution so far is not elegant and has a number of inefficiencies like a loop (depending on how large your data is, a vectorized implementation will be much faster) and more importantly a major disadvantage (but again I'd only be concerned if your data is really large) is that I am incrementing a list of a priori unknown length inside a loop. That is generally considered very bad practice as it is slow due to the fact that the memory is not pre-allocated, but again at least I think this works.

So, in the end I am trying to output a result structure (list) where for each valid case (a valid case is a v1 observation with at least 1 v2 observation in each of the 4 preceding weeks) I have the date of the v1 measurement, the v1 value at that date as well as the v2 values over the preceding weeks (if and only if **at least one** for each week in the preceding 4 weeks). In order to have at least one valid case, I slightly changed your `sample_data`in that I sneaked another v2 measurement for `id=1` on 2021-12-04. I think if my logic doesn't deceive me that otherwise you don't have a single valid case in your sample dataset. Here comes the code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# generate data frame
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1) # User ID
date <- c("2021-12-26", "2021-12-19", "2021-12-15", "2021-12-07", "2021-12-04", "2021-11-11", "2021-11-05", "2021-09-17","2021-09-17", "2021-10-08", "2021-10-06", "2021-10-01", "2021-09-30", "2022-01-30", "2022-01-24", "2022-01-18", "2022-01-13") # Date the form was submitted
variable1 <- c(10, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, 7, 6, 9, NA, NA, NA, 6, 8, NA, NA)
variable2 <- c(5,2,3,4,3,6,7,8,9,1,4,3,2,5,6,5,4)
sample_data <- data.frame(id, date, variable1, variable2)
sample_data <- sample_data %>%
  mutate(date=as.Date(date, format="%Y-%m-%d")) %>% 
  arrange(id, date)

result <- list()

v2_data_X_weeks_ago <- function(data, this_id, this_date, weeks_ago){
  
  from_date <- this_date - weeks(weeks_ago)
  to_date <- from_date + weeks(1)

  values <- data %>% 
    filter(id == this_id, !is.na(variable2), date <= to_date, date > from_date) %>% 
    pull(variable2)
  if(length(values) == 0) values <- NA # no v2 values for that week
  return(list(values = values, period = c(from_date, to_date)))
}

valid_entry <-  0
for (row in 1:nrow(sample_data)) {
  #print(sample_data[row,])
  if (is.na(sample_data$variable1[row])) next
  else {
    this_id <-sample_data$id[row]
    this_v1_date <- sample_data$date[row]
    
    v2_values <- c()
    for (w in 1:4) {
      v2_value <- v2_data_X_weeks_ago(sample_data, this_id, this_v1_date, w)$values
      v2_values <- c(v2_values, v2_value)
    }

    if (any(is.na(v2_values))) next
    else {
      valid_entry <- valid_entry + 1
      result[[valid_entry]] <- list(id = this_id,
                                    v1_date = this_v1_date,
                                    v1_value = sample_data$variable1[row],
                                    v2_values = v2_values)
    }

  }
  
}
```

In this case the only valid case is for `id=1` having an v1 entry on 2021-12-26 of 10, and v2 entries prior to that `[5 3 2 4 3]` - note that to of these there is at least one in each of the 4 weeks preceding 2021-12-26. How exactly you would like to "correlate" `10` with `[5 3 2 4 3]` I leave up to you.